# Google Sheets Query ignoring rules randomly, is not null?

Tags: mysql, null

struggling to understand what is happening here.

I have the following query in google sheets:

=query(datarange, "select AW where AX >= 0 AND "&I4&" is not null", 0)

I4 in this instance is returning a column value, for example BH.

The data contains 0, 1, 2,3 and so on.

This query is working perfectly a lot of the time, but sometimes it returns all the results but ignores the 0s. I need it to return all values that are not null.

Thanks in advance.

[Example of query working and not working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5HjC.png)

Sheet Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6mkDbONM1Nx0fccYCvtfjPawg9GXesVdCVZUwIllcY/edit#gid=933451035

Comment: It would be helpful if you link a view only copy of your sheet. If I4 is not part of the datarange that may be the reason for the inconsistent results.

Comment: Thanks JohnA for the comment, here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6mkDbONM1Nx0fccYCvtfjPawg9GXesVdCVZUwIllcY/edit?usp=sharing

This should like to a sheet called Dahlhaus, Luke. You can see on this page that the Goals and Disposals columns are counting correctly, however, the disposals columns ignores the 0s found on page titles Behinds. 

The query is found in cell M10. 

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the mix of data type in columns ( - in place of 0).

Looking at the 'Clark, Jordan' tab as an example, try the following:

Remove the `QUERY` formulas from cells A9, B9 and C9.

Put the following in A9:

`=arrayformula({Disposals!A7:B12,value(substitute(Disposals!I7:I12,"-",0))})`

You can always wrap a `QUERY` round this array if you need to. For instance, you could sort the array using:

`=query(arrayformula({Disposals!A7:B12,value(substitute(Disposals!I7:I12,"-","0"))}),"order by Col3" ,0)`

It depends if you want a separate column on the right for 'Reverse'.

Th above is probably going to be easier to manage than trying to convert '-' to 0 on the 'Behinds' tab.

The reason that the formula in cell L10 on 'Dahlhaus, Luke' is not working is because on 'Behinds' tab, your formula in cell BH7 is converting the hyphen to text '0'.

`=if(L7 = "-", "0", L8)` should be `=if(L7 = "-", 0, L7)`

However, this is a lot of manual work, having to use formula in every cell.

It would be more manageable to use `=arrayformula(if(L7:L = "-", 0, L7:L))` in cell BH7 and remove all other formula below.

Comment: Thank you so much Aresvik, that has solved the issue.

Really appreciate it, it's all working perfectly now just using the array. 

Legend!